# Intent: Only a specific setting page (without full control)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When I call the code below, the Wireless Settings get called. Is it possible to call this "activity" that he cant move through the whole settings? In the case below, that he is only  allowed to change the wireless settings.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: Alright, thanks. But who down voted that? Was a clear question.